# Why do I get undefined method `each' allowing user the view own content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, ruby-on-rails-3.2, undefined

I have been trying to get this working so that the current user signed in can only view stuff they have posted. I have almost cracked it I think, but I came across an undefined method `each' error.

These are the only two files I edited:

_form.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing programs</h1>

<table>

<% @programs.each do |program| %>
  <tr>
    <td><h2><%= program.title %></h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= program.body %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', program %> | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_program_path(program) %> | <%= link_to 'Destroy', program, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>    </td>
  </tr>

<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Program', new_program_path %>
```

programs_controller.rb

```
class ProgramsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_coach!, :except => [:show]


  # GET /programs
  # GET /programs.json

  def index
    @programs = Program.find(current_coach[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @programs }
    end
  end

  # GET /programs/1
  # GET /programs/1.json
  def show
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @program }
    end
  end

  # GET /programs/new
  # GET /programs/new.json
  def new
    @program = Program.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @program }
    end
  end

  # GET /programs/1/edit
  def edit
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /programs
  # POST /programs.json
  def create
    @program = Program.new(params[:program])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @program.save
        format.html { redirect_to @program, notice: 'Program was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @program, status: :created, location: @program }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @program.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /programs/1
  # PUT /programs/1.json
  def update
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @program.update_attributes(params[:program])
        format.html { redirect_to @program, notice: 'Program was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @program.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /programs/1
  # DELETE /programs/1.json
  def destroy
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])
    @program.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to programs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

The different models I have currently are `Program`, which is what the coach will post, and `Coach` (user):

program.rb:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :coach

  validates_presence_of :title
  attr_accessible :body, :title, :coach_id



end
```

coach.rb:

```
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :programs

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :firstname, :lastname, :coach
  # attr_accessible :title, :body


end
```

If you need any more details please let me know and I'll give them to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
@programs = Program.find_all_by_coach_id(current_coach[:id])
```

Or I suppose you should also change

```
current_coach[:id]
```

to

```
current_coach.id
```